# Is there any certain Tutorial for how to add plugin in nopCommerce through coding?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I created and downloaded nopCommerce for develop multi platform web site. I created theme but I can't change settings of pages from coding. Not getting how to do changes and crate plugin. Please share any tutorial that describe every steps in details of nopCommerce.
Thanking You.

Comment: Asking for a tutorial is too broad, please add details about your code.

Comment: You should check the docs. For instance [this document](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/developer/plugins/how-to-write-plugin-4.60.html) or [this one](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/developer/plugins/plugin-with-data-access.html). Then come back if you have more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking. Best way to learn plugin creation in nopcommerce is:

1. carefully studying existing plugins
2. check out its current code.
3. Copy it and rename it with a new plugin and make sure you can install that.
4. finally change files where in logic is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your nopCommerce solution in Visual Studio Community.
2. In the Solution Explorer, expand the "Presentation" folder.
3. You should see a "Themes" folder listed. Click on it to expand it.
4. Here you will see all the available themes for your nopCommerce
   site.
5. To access a specific theme, click on its folder to expand it.

Once you have navigated to the theme folder, you can make changes to the theme files such as .cshtml, .css, and .js files to customize the appearance of your nopCommerce site.

As for tutorials on how to create plugins and make changes to nopCommerce from code, the nopCommerce website has a documentation section that provides step-by-step tutorials on various topics related to nopCommerce development. Here's the link to the nopCommerce documentation: https://docs.nopcommerce.com/.

Answer (score -1):

the docs are here
https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/developer/plugins/how-to-write-plugin-4.60.html

NopCommerce is very robust, sometimes its hard to apply something, becuase you have to apply changes to many places.

what exactly you want to achieve ?